# Apache HTTPD reload

Tags: reload, apache

Does anyone know if while Apache HTTPD is doing a reload (which, let's say, takes five seconds) can it still serve requests during that time?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First of all, you say reload, but assuming you mean 'reload' OR 'restart':

```
   /my/path/to/httpd restart
```

- Causes the current httpd process to exit, which means for a time the server appears to be down, as in not serving any requests.

Reload on the other side:

```
    /my/path/to/httpd reload
```

- Does not cause the current server to exit, which means connections
  are never refused and thus the server never looks down (but is rather
  slow for a little while)
- Will cause all long running httpd daemon requests to exit

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. Sorry, I didn't mean 'reload' or 'restart'. Just 'reload'. I understand that a 'restart' brings the whole server down. I was just wondering about the 'reload'.

Comment: No worries, it's better to be clear about the difference between the two anyway. Hope that helped you.

Comment: ? http://mail.lon-capa.org/pipermail/lon-capa-admin/2004-July/000606.html ?

Comment: I would like add to this answer, that if you `reload` apache  with errors in config file nothing will happen, while if you `restart` apache server it will get down, and could not start because of errors in config file.

Comment: "Will cause all long running httpd daemon requests to exit": do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, no. However there is a graceful restart which stops child nodes halting mid-request which I think takes care of this.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html