# redirect remote domain through my domain

Tags: linux, dns, whm

I have a site, lets say it's called www.supersite.com. Now, I have a site called www.subsite.com. I would like to make calls to subsite return what is on supersite but keeping the url to subsite.

Now, to make it more interesting, the only change needed on subsite is this: Change www.subsite.com A record to {the IP of supersite}

I have full control of supersite, so if it needs any configuration for something like this, it can be done.

take care,
lee

Comment: Which web server do you use on www.supersite.com?

Comment: I am using Apache on Linux CentOS 5. I have WHM for the control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

Let the `A` record of `www.subsite.web` point to the *same* machine which runs `www.supersite.web`.

Then in the Apache configuration file of the machine which runs `www.supersite.web`, alias subsite and supersite using Apache's `ServerAlias` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.supersite.web
  ServerAlias www.subsite.web
</VirtualHost>
```

Read more about [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias) and [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the slow acceptance. Been out of town. Do you know if Apache has to be restarted each time this file is updated?

Comment: @LeeLoftiss - you can 'reload' it. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671667/apache-httpd-reload)